# SQL processing values of user defined columns

Tags: sql

I can do that:

```
SELECT
   1 AS one,
   2 AS two,
   1 + 2 AS three;
```

But I would like to do that:

```
SELECT
    1 AS one,
    2 AS two,
one + two AS three;
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

```
SELECT one, two, (one+two) as three
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
         1 AS one 
         2 AS two
) t;
```

Comment: +1 yep, that's the way to go - without a subselect or a CTE, one **cannot** use an column aliases in the same SELECT

Comment: Thanks, I tried that before but my problem became another: I have a couple of joins on my parent query and my "one" and "two" columns are sub-selects which use values from these joins. That means I would have to make those joins inside this SELECT that acts as a table. Thanks for the explanation marc_s btw!

Answer (score 2):

A way is this:

```
SELECT one, two, one + two AS 'three'
FROM (SELECT 1 as 'one', 2 as 'two') myTable
```